# CGLayers not drawing to screen

Tags: macos, cocoa, drawing, quartz-2d

What's wrong with my drawRect: code?

Create CGContextRef for drawing

```
   CGContextRef myContext = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
```

Create CGLayerRef with current context

```
   CGLayerRef theLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(myContext, CGSizeMake(5, 5) NULL);
```

Create a CGContextRef for the layer itself

```
   CGContextRef theCurrentLayer = CGLayerGetContext(theLayer);
```

Get location of mouse, to be used as origin

```
   NSPoint point = [self.window mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream];
```

Set color to black

```
   CGContextSetRGBFillColor(theCurrentLayer, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

Draw a rectangle to the layer

```
   CGContextFillRect (theCurrentLayer, CGRectMake (point.x, point.y, 5, 5));
```

Draw the layer to the current context at the mouse location

```
   CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(myContext, CGPointMake(point.x, point.y), theLayer);
```

And nothing happens… Memory usage increases steadily indicating that the layers are being created, but nothing appears in the window.

Comment: Does it work if tou're not using the mouse.ocation? If yes, you may have to calculate mouse pos to your view coordinate system.

Comment: Did you added this custom View as subview to your view controller?